# alignment and assembly in IA32

Tags: assembly, x86, alignment

[image]

Can someone explain to me why in the second question proco2, that x-> b.i -> f[3]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually on the stack you only have a pointer to the `struct s2` (in `8(%ebp)`). Therefore after

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
```

in `%eax` you have an address of **`struct s2`**.

The 8th-11th bytes of `struct s2` constitute `f[0]` and the 12th-15th bytes constitute **`f[1]`** and therefore you have

```
return x->f[1]
```

In the second case after

```
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
```

in `%eax` you have an address of **`struct s1`**.

The 4th-7th bytes of `struct s1` constitute the **`b`** field of type `union u1`. Therefore after

```
movl 4(%eax), %eax
```

in `%eax` you have `union u1`. Since it's a `union` the `%eax` contains all field values at the same time (`h`, `i` and `j`). So

```
movl 20(%eax), %eax
```

is actually getting the 20th-23th byte of whatever pointer is in `%eax` (it can't be the `j` field since it's not a pointer). It can't be `h` field since it points to `struct s1` and `sizeof (struct s1)` is 12 which is <20. Therefore it must be the **`i`** field. The 20th-23th byte of `struct s2` is **`f[3]`** and therefore you have:

```
return x->b.i->f[3]
```

Comment: can you explain the second one? how did it get to b.i?

Comment: and for the first question, is 8th-11th bytes of struct s2 -> f[0]?

Comment: @Jenny I edited the answer so that it contains the second case and the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

mov 8(%ebp), %eax ;; eax = &x
mov 4(%eax), %eax ;; eax = x->b   (or x->e)

More likely x->e would have had movsbl 4(%eax), %eax //; sign extension
or mov 4(%eax), %al  with sign extension

Because char can't (shouldn't) be used as a pointer, the 4(%eax) was a ptr to struct.
Which struct? 20%(eax) exists only for struct s2, unless originally there was an array os structs s1.

Offset 20 of s2 is f[3].